# How would I create the following with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Id like to create this using jquery.

```
       <div class="row" style="background-color:white;margin:5px; "> 

        <ul class="nav pull-left" style="text-align:center; margin:5px">
            <li style="font-size:10px"><b>List2</b></li>
        </ul>

       </div>
```

Comment: create what? Did you hit `Post your question` button before you finished typing? A little html with no details is hardly a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create using this:

```
 var element = $('<div class="row" style="background-color:white;margin:5px; "> 
        <ul class="nav pull-left" style="text-align:center; margin:5px">
            <li style="font-size:10px"><b>List2</b></li>
        </ul>
  </div>')
```

check this fiddle for more details: http://jsfiddle.net/victorrseloy/vPsdz/